# Local h-polynomial with V=3.

Tags: combinatorics, combinatorial-proofs, combinatorial-geometry, triangulation, algebraic-combinatorics

I'm trying to understand an example that Stanley gives in his article "Subdivisions and local h vectors". It is example 2.3 part d).

> If #V=3 and $h(\Gamma,x)=h_0+h_1x+h_2x^2+h_3x^3$ (so $h_0=1$ and $h_3=0)$, then $$\ell_V(\Gamma,x)=h_2x+h_2x^2.$$

I was trying using

$$\ell_V(\Gamma,x)=\sum_{W\subseteq V}(-1)^{|V-W|}h(\Gamma_W,x).$$
Then I have
\begin{split}
\ell_V(\Gamma,x)&=-1+3-(h(\Gamma_{1,2},x)+h(\Gamma_{1,3},x)+h(\Gamma_{2,3},x))+(h_0+h_1x+h_2x^2+h_3x^3)\\
&=-x(h(\Gamma_{1,2})+h(\Gamma_{1,3})+h(\Gamma_{2,3}))+h_1x+h_2x^2.
\end{split}

And I know that $h(\Gamma_{1,2})+h(\Gamma_{1,3})+h(\Gamma_{2,3})$ are the interior vertices of $\Gamma$, but it is not clear to me how to reach the final conclusion.
I really appreciate any help or ideas.